# C++. При использовании "va_arg" ошибка преобразования типов (невозможно преобразовать float в float *)

Tags: c++, преобразование

Привет! Помогите пожалуйста. 
Есть класс Hero -

```
class Hero
{
public:
    ...
    float wins;
    ...
}
```

Есть функция Result

```
int Result(float draw, Hero Args, ...)
{
    int i = 0; float wins;
    va_list list;
    va_start(list, Args);
    while (i != 2)
    {
        wins = va_arg(Args.wins, float);
        cout << wins << endl;
        i++;
    }
    va_end(list);
    return 0;
}
```

При компиляции получаю ошибку - "приведение типов: невозможно преобразовать "float" в "float *"... Причем тот же фокус с INT переменными в том же классе - канает :(

Comment: Перематывать va_arg по классу или структуре - это вообще очень странная идея как минимум... Ну и потом: `type va_arg(va_list ap, type);`, у вас не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пользуйтесь правильно!

```
    wins = va_arg(list, float);
```

и все у вас получится... По крайней мере VC++ отлично все понимает и работает...

**Update**
По поводу обращения к полям... Вот реальный живой компилируемый код для VC++ 2015:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Test
{
    float a,b,c;
    Test(float x):a(x),b(2*x),c(x*x){};
};

float Sum(int count, Test Args, ...)
{
    float sum = Args.a;
    va_list list;
    va_start(list, Args);
    for(int i = 0; i < count-1; ++i)
    {
        sum += va_arg(list, Test).a;
    }
    va_end(list);
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    cout << Sum(3,Test(2.0),Test(4.0),Test(5.0)) << endl;
}
```

Как видите, передавать можно разные объекты.

Comment: К сожалению, это точно не получится т.к. необходим доступ к значениям внутри класса, что, как пояснили ниже, увы, нельзя :(

Comment: Вы хотите передавать туда объекты Hero? Проще всего - передавайте их адреса, в чем проблемы?

Comment: См. дополнение к ответу.

Comment: Спасибо большое! И правда работает исправно. Еще один маленький вопрос... Можно ли как то в одном цикле два раза обратиться к одной и той же переменной с помощью va_arg?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, нет. Каждый va_arg обращается к следующему аргументу. Сохраняйте его в переменной, например...

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятно что должен делать этот код. Но для начала:

```
type va_arg(va_list ap, type);
```

Передавать туда первым аргументом `Args.wins` неверно. Дальше, если это поправить, то g++ выдаёт следующее:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int Result(float, Hero, ...)’:
main.cpp:14:29: warning: ‘float’ is promoted to ‘double’ when passed through ‘...’ [enabled by default]
         wins = va_arg(list, float);
                             ^
main.cpp:14:29: note: (so you should pass ‘double’ not ‘float’ to ‘va_arg’)
main.cpp:14:29: note: if this code is reached, the program will abort
```

Но и это мелочи по сравнению с главной ошибкой. Нельзя передавать в обработку `va_*` структуру, не говоря уж о классе. И вот почему:

```
struct Hero {
  char c;
  short s;
  double d;
};

printf("%lu, %lu\n", sizeof(Hero), sizeof(char)+sizeof(short)+sizeof(double));
```

В моём случае выведется `16, 11`, но не факт, что так будет в вашем :) `va_*` ориентируются на размеры типов, но в случае структур они не могут этого делать из-за выравнивания полей.

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ. Код действительно неясен, вырезал большую часть, как не представляющую интереса. А может вы сможете подсказать, как можно обращаться к случайному количеству переменных типа класс?

Comment: Не проще ли передавать массив или контейнер в функцию:``float Sum(int count, const std::vector<Test> &arr)`` ?